# A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net, excel, export-to-excel

I am getting an error message when running the below code it occurs on the rng = .Range.Copy From Recordset line.  The error is "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll".  I know it isn't the output as the code that is commented out works fine albeit very slow.  I was working on a way to speed this up.  Here is the code

```
    Private Sub ButRun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButRun.Click
    Dim DWPROD As String = "Data Source=DWPROD;User ID=gayloj01;password=jgay0421;"
    Dim Conn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    Dim cmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dtAdapter As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter
    Dim Excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim rng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

    SQLBuilder()
    Conn.ConnectionString = DWPROD
    With cmd
        .Connection = Conn
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With
    dtAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    ds.Tables.Add("RawData")
    dtAdapter.Fill(ds, "RawData")
    Try
        Excel = CType(GetObject(, "Excel.Application"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    End Try
    Try
        With Excel
            .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
            .Workbooks.Add()
            .Worksheets(1).Select()
            .Visible = True
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(ds.Tables("RawData").Rows.Count, ds.Tables("RawData").Columns.Count))
            rng.CopyFromRecordset(ds.Tables("RawData"), ds.Tables("RawData").Rows.Count, ds.Tables("RawData").Columns.Count)
            'Dim i As Integer = 1
            'For col = 0 To ds.Tables("RawData").Columns.Count - 1
            '.Cells(1, i).value = ds.Tables("RawData").Columns(col).ColumnName
            '.Cells(1, i).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
            'i += 1
            'Next
            'i = 2
            'Dim j As Integer = 1
            'For col = 0 To ds.Tables("RawData").Columns.Count - 1
            'i = 2
            'For row = 0 To ds.Tables("RawData").Rows.Count - 1
            '.Cells(i, j).Value = ds.Tables("RawData").Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
            'i += 1
            'Next
            'j += 1
            'Next
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I am thinking it has to do with how I am filling the range, but I can't fiund any issues with it.  I am very new to VB.net and would appreciate any help that can be provided.

TIA

Jim G

Answer (score 5):

First-chance exceptions happen when you are debugging and it is the .NET Framework's way of giving the debugger (i.e. Visual Studio) an opportunity to handle the problem. If the debugger is unable to resolve the first-chance exception, then it will become an exception that your code is expected to handle. If your code does not handle the exception, then ultimately the .NET Framework will handle it (i.e. yellow screen of death in ASP.NET).

You can ignore first-chance exceptions, because they are intended for the debugger. In other words, your exception code (`try-catch` logic) will not let you interact with first-chance exceptions.